# Flask_dance with Google API; Missing required parameter: refresh_token

Tags: python, flask

I trid to make authorization system with flask_dance and Google.
I was successful in authorize first but after a while, the program caused this error even though I didn't change it at all. 
My whole code is here (It's almost the same as the tutorial one though

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "supersekrit"
blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id="",
client_secret="",
scope=["profile", "email"]
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    resp = google.get("/oauth2/v2/userinfo")
    assert resp.ok, resp.text
    return "You are {email} on Google".format(email=resp.json()["email"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be the one referenced [in this Github issue](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance/issues/102#issuecomment-353674109). The suggested solution is to request **offline access**:

```
google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id='',
    client_secret='',
    scope=['profile', 'email'],
    offline=True
)
```